# System Icons disappear at projected screens

Tags: windows, taskbar

I got the new Win11 (on a Lenovo X1 Yoga) and when I project my the screen (to 2 more screens) I can't find a way to add/see the system icons on the taskbar on the 2 additional screens, but only on the main screen (which is the laptop, by choice).

How can I change that in order to see the system icons on all 3 screens, or at least the clock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 11 Taskbar is fixed to one screen and cannot be split up. This may change in future but right now, just one screen natively.

[Windows 11 Taskbar](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-taskbar-multiple-monitors/)

> The taskbar will automatically switch to the main monitor you
> assigned. So, if the Windows 11 taskbar is not showing on a second
> monitor, there is a simple workaround. It’s not ideal, but until
> Microsoft is solving this problem, we’re stuck with it, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you, John.

Comment: You might consider acknowledging my answer as I have confirmed what is possible.